# How to make finite automaton for this language?

Tags: formal-languages, automata, finite-automata

Consider the language
$$ L = \{0^p 1^q 0^p | p, q ≥ 0\}. $$
How to make a finite automaton for $L$? How to make a regular expression for $L$?

Comment: Your language isn't regular.

Comment: You cannot. It is impossible.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! We discourage posts that simply state a problem out of context, and expect the community to solve it. Assuming you tried to solve it yourself and got stuck, it may be helpful if you wrote your thoughts and what you could not figure out. It will definitely draw more answers to your post. Until then, the question will be voted to be closed / downvoted. You may also want to check out [these hints](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98), or use the search engine of this site to find similar questions that were already answered.